# Laravel unable to load FFProbe?

Tags: php, laravel, ffmpeg

I'm using the PHP-FFMpeg repository to do some video work inside my Laravel application, but I'm encountering some issues setting it up. Once I've installed the PHP-FFMpeg repo, I try and create an `FFMpeg` instance:

```
$ffmpeg = \FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create();
```

However, this does not work. In response, I get an ErrorException that simply states:

```
Unable to load FFProbe
```

This does not make sense to me, as when I run `ffmpeg` and `ffprobe` from my Mac's terminal, I can see they are installed. This is clearly a path/resolving issue, but I'm unsure how to fix it. Any ideas?

This is all hosted under a MAMP project, running on localhost.

Comment: Have you found any solution mate , i am also facing the same issue , Help would be appreciable . Thanks

Comment: Same issue for me also, still not get a solution

Answer (score 13):

For Mac OS :

```
'ffmpeg.binaries'  => '/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg',
'ffprobe.binaries' => '/usr/local/bin/ffprobe'
```

For Windows :

```
'ffmpeg.binaries'  => 'C:/FFmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe',
'ffprobe.binaries' => 'C:/FFmpeg/bin/ffprobe.exe'
```

For Ubantu :

```
'ffmpeg.binaries' => '/usr/bin/ffmpeg',   
'ffprobe.binaries' => '/usr/bin/ffprobe'

sudo apt install ffmpeg
```

Comment: What about on the server?

Comment: i have installed the ffmpeg using composer in my php project, and i m unable to find the .exe file and bin folder, i am searching in vendor folder

Answer (score 11):

```
$ffmpeg = \FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create([
    'ffmpeg.binaries'  => '/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg',
    'ffprobe.binaries' => '/usr/local/bin/ffprobe' 
]);
```

your ffmpeg installation path.

that is what @limonte means, and it is working to me.

Comment: How to keep that link on server (cpanel)?

Answer (score 10):

Specifying paths to binaries should help:

```
$ffmpeg = \FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create([
    'ffmpeg.binaries'  => exec('which ffmpeg'),
    'ffprobe.binaries' => exec('which ffprobe')
]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but sadly, this did not help me. I still get the same error.

Comment: This helped me figure out that the `ffmpeg` package wasn't installed. On ubuntu, I had to run `sudo apt-get install ffmpeg`, which installed it in `/usr/bin`. Bottom line, make sure the package is installed!!!

Answer (score 6):

I spent a lot of time in researching this and I am posting this answer for anyone experiencing similar issue on windows. The library removes the backslashes

```
(D:\binaries\ffmpeg\ffmpeg.exe)
```

so you should use forward slashes instead

```
(D:/binaries/ffmpeg/ffmpeg.exe)
```

this will work on widows. Hope this helps

Comment: from where i can get .exe file. i have install the ffmpeg library using composer in my project,

Comment: Oh, Your answer helped me so much! Hours upon hours of searching the web. Thank you.

Comment: this worked for me

FFMPEG_PATH=c:/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe
FFPROBE_PATH=c:/ffmpeg/bin/ffprobe.exe

Answer (score 1):

For me it was rather un-related.

I was using SpatieMedia with ffmpeg to clip a video, store it in a temp folder then save .webm in the same directory created by spatiemedia.

The Ffprobe was loading right, it was the hard-coded paths in spatie-media which were wrong.

Fix
vendor\spatie\laravel-medialibrary\config\media-library.php
Changed those line to this, on my server Ubuntu 20

```
'ffmpeg_path' => '/usr/bin/ffmpeg',
    'ffprobe_path' =>  '/usr/bin/ffprobe',
```

---

vendor\spatie\laravel-medialibrary\src\Conversions\ImageGenerators\Video.php
Same change in convert() function

```
  $ffmpeg = FFMpeg::create([
            'ffmpeg.binaries' => '/usr/bin/ffmpeg',
            'ffprobe.binaries' => '/usr/bin/ffprobe',
    ]);
```

Answer (score -1):

If the above solution didn't work for you.

unable to load FFProbe?

or

file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/usr/bin/ffprobe) is not within the allowed path(s):

Make you Update open_basedir Directive:

for Plesk goto php and that

```
{WEBSPACEROOT}{/}{:}{TMP}{/}:/usr/bin/ffmpeg:/usr/bin/ffprobe
```

You would need to add /usr/bin (or the appropriate path) to the list of allowed directories in the open_basedir directive in your server's PHP configuration file (php.ini). After making this change, you may need to restart your web server for the changes to take effect.